# In Objective-C, what is the standard way of extending and augmenting the behaviour of init?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, objective-c-category

[Categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) are used in Objective-C to implement extensions onto existing classes.

This is great for supplying new methods that could be used, but does not necessarily help augmenting behaviours of the existing class methods.

In particular, I'm interested in extending `init` methods and customize them such that necessary set up for my category is performed at object initialization time. If you must know, these are ReactiveCocoa signals that I'd like set up once per object lifetime. This ideally should go in `init`.

The obvious way of doing this is to call a `setUpXYZExtension` method defined in the category directly from `init`. However, this means the main source file now has knowledge of the extension. i.e. deleting the extension source file will lead to a compile error because the method `setUpXYZExtension` will not be found.

Is there a potentially neater way of doing this, such that when the category's source file is deleted, there is no compile error?

Comment: As long as these are just singleton objects, you could always `dispatch_once()` them to life in `+load` or `+initialize` as long as you know the object itself doesn't implement those methods too.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about this being standard but you can look at method swizzling. Swizzling allows you to either extend or exchange the implementation of methods of current classes.

http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/